Migrate public contract with property of JObject type from Newtonsoft to System.Text with backward-compatibility
I have a contract defined like this:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Foo 
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public JObject Value { get; set; }
}

Type property defines the type which Value is deserialized to.
This contract is used by 2 separate microservices.
One of microservices wants to switch to System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft while another microservice will still use Newtonsoft for some time.
It's fine with Type property - I just add JsonPropertyName("type") attribute from System.Text.Json.
But what to do with Value property? It's type is already a JObject - type defined in Newtonsoft. What is a correct way to handle it?

Why does it matter? You can use Newtownsoft on client and STJ on server...

My question is how to serialize JObject using STJ and how to deserialize to JObject using STJ

You need to use JsonObject instead... But as I wrote it doesn't matter on the other side... So you can use NS.JObject on one side of the serialisation and STJ.JsonObject on the other

This does not help me, since the type Foo is used on both sides. What I currently came up is  (1) adding a new property STJ.JsonObject ValueJsonObject {get;set;} which has STJ annotations with same JSON name, (2) marking properties with JsonIgnore attribute from appropriate assembly respectively (so Value is ignored by STJ and ValueJsonObject is ignored by Newtonsoft). This solution keeps json the same, has backward compatibility, each side can decide what to use by using in the code appropriate property.

Use shared project instead assembly with model use conditional (#if STJ/NS) and define STJ/NS in projects. Then you don't have to add both STJ and na assemblies to each project

Do you want your final data model to have JObject or JsonObject?  If you want to keep using JObject, you could use a System.Text.Json JsonConverter to serialize & deserialize it, such as the one from this answer to How can I serialize a Newtonsoft JToken to JSON using System.Text.Json?.  You would apply [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JTokenConverterFactory))] to public JObject Value { get; set; }

If you would prefer to make your data model use JsonObject you will need to create a Newtonsoft converter for it.

But your question asks, What is a correct way to handle it?.  We can't really answer that in a factual way without knowing more about what you are going to do with your Foo class.  What code do you need to share between the two microservices?  And absent that information your question is kind of (though not completely) opinion based.

@Selvin can you share with some guide with me? Currently I use this library as a Nuget package. What should I do to switch for shared project in this case ?

@dbc I do not wanted for opinions, but for possible solutions with pro/contra. Which could probably go from personal expirience.

After some time I will answer my question...
Initially I asked about correct ways to handle such situations. This was not a correct question, basically I meant what a possible ways to do Newtonsoft -> STJ migration with backward-compatibility.

Add separate STJ.JsonObject propery.
Such class will look like

    [Newtonsoft.JsonProperty("value")]
    [STJ.JsonIgnore]
    public JObject Value { get; set; }

    [STJ.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    [Newtonsoft.JsonIgnore]
    public JsonObject ValueJsonObject { get; set; }

Such way we will have only one property being not null - depending on the serialzer we use. Those who still use Newtonsoft will still use Value, those who migrated to ST will use ValueJsonObject. In JSON we will have same value regardless serializer we use.
It is simple to implement, but classes start look odd, though this is might be an opinion; You need to select right property to use - this is possible mistake.

Use shared project and compile appropriate code only. As @Selvin adviced in comments to the question.

public class Foo
{
#if NEWTONSOFT
    [Newtonsoft.JsonProperty("value")]
    public JObject Value { get; set; }
#elif STJ
    [STJ.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public JsonObject Value { get; set; }
#end
}


Refactor this code so the class becomes generic, replacing JObject tith T type parameter:

public class Foo<T>
{
    [Newtonsoft.JsonProperty("value")]
    [STJ.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

This will have only json-compatibility, you will have to refactor source code when other people update the library's version.
